# Generating random number in C on R-Pi

Tags: c, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to generate a simple random number in C with the raspberry pi. The code compiles fine but when running it the number is not random, its 384 each time.

Where am I going wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)

{
    printf ("Random number generator\n") ;

    int x = (rand() % 1000) + 1;
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to seed the random number generator with some naturally random value like the current time.  Something like:

```
srand (time(NULL));
```

Update: note that you will need to add an include for the time library if you use the example above:

```
include <time.h>
```

Comment: Why not use the [hardware random generator of the Pi](http://scruss.com/blog/2013/06/07/well-that-was-unexpected-the-raspberry-pis-hardware-random-number-generator/)

Comment: @DavidKarlsson - Thanx for the new info. Very cool hardware. Might someday replace ping pong balls ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to generate random value. also make sure to add the library include <time.h>.

```
  //    Random value will be from 0 to #
int GenerateRandomInt (int MaxValue)
{
    unsigned int iseed = (unsigned int)time(NULL);          //Seed srand() using time() otherwise it will start from a default value of 1
    srand (iseed);
    int random_value = (int)((1.0 + MaxValue) * rand() / ( RAND_MAX + 1.0 ) );      //Scale rand()'s return value against RAND_MAX using doubles instead of a pure modulus to have a more distributed result.
    return(random_value);
}
```

Comment: Note: You should call the `srand()` function *once* - not each time you want another random number.